# SUMIF/SUMPRODUCT match multiple criteria within date range

Tags: excel-2010, criteria, matching, date-range

I have a [table (Sales)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ47o.jpg) data that has two sets of columns with code, amounts and date reference:

[image]

And I have another [table (Sheet1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S94PM.jpg):
[image]
which need to sum the total net amount with one set subtract the other set on the **Sales** table but it have to matched the code and based on the weekly date range in **Sheet1** table. I can sum the total amount together but I can't separate it with date.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far! And honestly I don't understand if this is TSQL, Oracle, LINQ in C#, Access, Excel, ... Tagging your query with technology will help you get relevant responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=SUMIFS(Sales!I:I,Sales!F:F,$A4,Sales!G:G,$C4,Sales!H:H,">="&Sheet1!D$1,Sales!H:H,"<="&Sheet1!D$2)
```

IF you want the difference between the sum of the blues and the sum of the reds subject to the same conditions, repeat the above (with adjustments to suit) at the beginning and link the two together with a `-`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i try using sumproduct and it did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've work this one out. This is my formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sales!$C$1:$C$1000>=$C$1),--(Sales!$C$1:$C$1000<=$C$2),--(Sales!$A$1:$A$1000=A4),Sales!$D$1:$D$1000)-SUMPRODUCT(--(Sales!$H$1:$H$1000>=$C$1),--(Sales!$H$1:$H$1000<=$C$2),--(Sales!$A$1:$A$1000=A4),Sales!$I$1:$I$1000)